# Does Stack Exchange use "acceptable" ads according to Adblock Plus?

Tags: discussion, advertising

As many have probably realized, Adblock Plus is now by-default allowing certain acceptable ads. In my opinion the Stack Exchange network has unobtrusive ads especially once you cross the "reduced advertising" threshold.

Has the team considered contacting the authors of Adblock Plus and requesting being on their acceptable-ad list?

Comment: I manually added Stack Exchange to my whitelist :-)

Comment: @Rocket: Same here.

Comment: I typically don't click on ads anyway out of principle. It's kind of like buying from the door-to-door salesman. Though perhaps we could arrange a day where the people of meta.stackoverflow.com made demands such as the abdication of all double-diamond mods. If the demands were met we could throw a "click-on-ads party".

Comment: @EvanCarroll: I don't agree with that analogy.  The door-to-door salesman isn't otherwise providing a service, this website is.  Not that I feel any compulsion to click on ads solely because of that, but I've certainly encountered ads on StackOverflow which I've followed.

Comment: Oh Evan, controversial as ever lol

Comment: Yea -- you know me though. I shine the good light of information, accountability, and transparency. Unfortunately for Jeff he can't dispatch his armies to downvote me in comments. At least, not until they're finished building the site and they add that functionality.

Comment: @Earlz Found the official ABP ticket #1905 requesting joining the Acceptable Ads Manifesto. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 8):

While doing research for answering [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266875/does-stack-exchange-support-this-responsible-web-content-blocking-bypass-switch) I found out that  Stack Exchange logo displayed under the '**We the undersigned…**' section of [Acceptable Ads](https://acceptableads.org/) main page. Click on the 'Additional organizations' link to expand the list of organizations. Here is the screenshot:

> [image]

Acceptable Ads manifesto says:

> We, the undersigned, want to make the Internet a better place for
>   everyone. We'll start by getting rid of obnoxious ads... read [full
>   details](https://acceptableads.org/)

Also, as per [Dean Murphy](http://murphyapps.co/blog/2015/9/25/on-acceptable-ads) 'Crystal iOS app' developer:

> Acceptable Ads is an initiative, supported by 3 of my favourite
>   websites  (Reddit, DuckDuckGo, Stack Exchange), that encourages and
>   promotes the use of better advertising on the web

Also found ticket #1905 that was opened on 01/29/2015 (which was closed on 02/09/2015) for [Adding Stack Exchange to acceptableads.org](https://issues.adblockplus.org/ticket/1905) which states:

> Stack Exchange would like to join the Acceptable Ads Manifesto on
>   acceptableads.org.

Comment: Absolutely hilarious after reading [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329547/269301), [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335497/269301), [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334537/269301) and other [high-scoring questions tagged 'inappropriate-advertisements'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inappropriate-advertisements?tab=Votes).