# Does Stack Exchange support this responsible web content blocking bypass switch?

Tags: discussion, advertising, privacy

With iOS 9 content blocker's rubber meeting the road this past week, one of the top paid apps this week on the Apple App Store has announced publicly that Stack Exchange supports "Acceptable Ads" and/or the Acceptable Ads Manifesto:

- https://acceptableads.org/
- http://murphyapps.co/blog/2015/9/25/on-acceptable-ads

Dean's text is as follows:

> Acceptable Ads is an initiative, supported by 3 of my favourite websites  (Reddit, DuckDuckGo, Stack Exchange), that encourages and promotes the use of better advertising on the web.

I don't see the Stack Overflow logo (or the old Stack Exchange) logo supporting the manifesto, so I wondered to what extent this statement is valid and what form of support is being unofficially or officially offered to one or all of the following:

- Dean Murphy and [Crystal iOS app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/crystal-block-ads-browse-faster./id1022177308?mt=8)
- acceptableads.org
- https://eyeo.com/

Comment: The only thing I can find is this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116254/does-stack-exchange-use-acceptable-ads-according-to-adblock-plus. There was no reply from the admins

Answer (score 9):

> I don't see the Stack Overflow logo (or the old Stack Exchange) logo
>   supporting the manifesto...

There is a Stack Exchange logo in the '**We the undersigned…**' section of [Acceptable Ads](https://acceptableads.org/) main page. Click on the 'Additional organizations' link to expand the list of organizations. Here is the screenshot:

> [image]

Also found ticket #1905 that was opened on 01/29/2015 (which was closed on 02/09/2015) for [Adding Stack Exchange to acceptableads.org](https://issues.adblockplus.org/ticket/1905) which states:

> Stack Exchange would like to join the Acceptable Ads Manifesto on
>   acceptableads.org.

Comment: Very cool - that looks pretty official in terms of support.