# What rules should I add to my AdBlock whitelist to allow Community Ads?

Tags: support, advertising

I use AdBlock, not because I hate ads, but because I hate **bad** ads. That's why I always allow it to display what are considered non-intrusive or 'acceptable' ads. Stack Exchange is great since it only ever shows 'good' ads.

As stated in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116254/does-stack-exchange-use-acceptable-ads-according-to-adblock-plus) and shown [on the Acceptable Ads homepage](https://acceptableads.org/) (click additional organisations), Stack Exchange has signed an agreement to only show acceptable ads, and as such has been added to the whitelist.

However, **community ads don't seem to be showing up**.

What filters should I add to my whitelist so that I can see Community Advertisements?

Comment: I see them from time to time... It's not consistent but I **do** see them occasionally.